# gwt 2.7 Super Dev Mode How to recompile?

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-2.7

I am migrating from gwt 2.6.1 to 2.7

When I launch super dev mode, I cannot recompile my application by clicking on the bookmark *Dev Mode On*. Clicking on *Dev Mode Off* then *Dev Mode On* works but I don't think this is the good way to use SDM.

I heard with gwt 2.7 there is no need to use the bookmarks anymore, but how to launch the super dev mode without clicking on the bookmarks ? (If I don't click on the bookmark I don't see my changes)

Comment: How do you run SDM? CodeServer or DevMode? If CodeServer, with launcherDir?

Answer (score 1):

In super dev mode you just need to refresh the page to see the client-side changes.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, its like if there is no link between my webapp and the superdev mode url (127.0.0.1:9876), when I click on the bookmark it's ok but I can't recompile. Do I miss some arguments to start the super dev mode (I have just the arg -noserver and the name of my module)

Comment: Which arguments do you use to launch the app in SDM?

Comment: 'when I click on the bookmark it's ok but I can't recompile. ' - you don't need bookmarks in 2.7.0, guess that's the issue

Comment: I use the arguments -superDevMode -codeServerPort -noserver -startupUrl -war and -bindAddress. I understood that I don't need anymore the bookmarks, so my question is how to link the super dev mode with my webapp deployed on the server, because when I lanch the super dev mode and I go to 127.0.0.1/my-webapp/index.html it doesn't recompile my application when I do some changes in the code.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. I created a sample project and I ran it with the embedded jetty server, when I edit the html page in firefox I see that 2 script tags where added ad the beginning of the head tag, <script src="http://127.0.0.1:9876/testsuperdevmode/testsuperdevmode.nocache.js"></script><script src="http://127.0.0.1:9876/recompile-requester/testsuperdevmode"></script>, when I launch the webapp in a remote jboss server I don't see these 2 script tags added